# Black screen after unity updated to 2019.4.17and later on Android

Tags: unity, android

I upgraded my app from Unity 2019.4.9 to 2019.4.21.  it seems to work fine in the editor, but on my Android build I just get a blank screen.  No splash screen, no app main window.  I've been able to isolate it to the update from 2019.4.16 to .17 that breaks it.  I can toggle back and forth, build .16 it works, .17 and higher are all black screen.  I tried (.17,.18 and .21)

only thing relevant in the logs seems to be:

```
03-13 10:49:09.689  1458  7484 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{378e77 u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-13 10:49:09.689  1458  7484 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
03-13 10:49:09.689  1458  2335 I ActivityManager: Process com.mycompany.myapp (pid 8851) has died: fore TOP (366,458)
```

i'm building for Mono, .NET 4.x and Targeting ARMv7

anyone else run into this?  any info on what I should look at next to continue to debug?  anyone know what changed in .17 that might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone is interested.  I didn't find a real fix so I created a new project in 2019.4.28 and manually imported all my code and assets.  After this it works as expected.